# What is the best way to export and import ARC2 RDF data?

Tags: php, import, export, rdf, sparql

Initially, I did this the wrong way:

- I used MySQL to copy the tables.

This was bad because ARC2 uses a platform-dependent hashing function for one of it's table columns.

So, I think the solution is simple:

```
// To export
$store->createBackup('backup_file.spog');

// To import
$store->query('LOAD <file://FULL_PATH_TO_FILE/backup_file.spog>');
```

I wanted to post this question, in case anyone has more suggestions. I am still new to RDF and ARC2.

More information on the ARC2 issue:

- For looking up a subject URI in the MySQL database, ARC2 uses the http://php.net/crc32 hashing function. The resulting integer is not 32 bits. Even though crc32() prepares a checksum using the "input string in 32-bit lengths at a time", the resulting integer value is platform-dependent, which can be seen in the PHP_INT_SIZE and PHP_INT_MAX constants

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No answers have been posted to this question (except the answer I proposed in my question), so I'm just going to answer my own question. The only option must be the one that I had found so far... apparently there are no other ways to do full import/export dumps in ARC2, except...

```
// To export
$store->createBackup('backup_file.spog');

// To import
$store->query('LOAD <file://FULL_PATH_TO_FILE/backup_file.spog>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes creating a SPOG backup seems to be the most straightforward option. However I had some problems one day and I used an rdf export instead:

```
$ser = ARC2::getRDFXMLSerializer();
$all = $store->query("SELECT ?s ?p ?o WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }");
$rdfxml2 = $ser->getSerializedTriples($all['result']['rows']);  
file_put_contents('storename.rdf', $rdfxml2);
```

Comment: I see, so you are saving the data to an RDF file. Importing and exporting is very slow. Have you noticed any improvement with this method?

Comment: I mean, when I was importing and exporting using the SPOG backup method it was slow. So, my hope is there is another method out there that is faster.